# Rank using ntile based on specific window function (PySpark)

Tags: python, pyspark

In the code below I create a pyspark dataframe with the following features, id, date and score. The date represents quarters. Then I rank 'score' using ntile. The rank is global, covering the complete dataframe.

However, I want to perform the ranking for each observation based on the last two years of data.

What is an elegant solution to that problem? Is it for example possible to do a partition using a condition?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

# Generate the data using pandas
num_observations = 1000
num_dates = 20

dates = pd.date_range(start='2017-01-01', periods=num_dates, freq='3M')
df_pandas = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': range(1, num_observations + 1),
    'date': sorted(list(dates) * (num_observations // num_dates + 1))[:num_observations],
    'score': np.random.normal(loc=400, scale=25, size=num_observations).astype(int)
})

# Create SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

# Convert pandas DataFrame to PySpark DataFrame
df_spark = spark.createDataFrame(df_pandas)

from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

window = Window.orderBy(F.col('score'))

# Global rank
df_spark = df_spark.withColumn('ranked_score', F.ntile(10).over(window))

# Window rank
```

Answer (score 0):

You can update your window to use rowsBetween or rangeBetween, this way it only compares it to the rows within the specified window.

Comment: Ok, then I need to order on both score and date?

Comment: Like this? (this produce an error) window_spec = (
    Window.orderBy(F.col('score'), F.col('date'))
           .rowsBetween(-8, Window.currentRow)
)

Comment: And how do I know how many rows? Since I want the date column to control the window ( 2 years back).

Comment: Ah now I see that rangebetween is not compatible with the ntile function unfortunately. If you want to create a sliding window, you can use
    Window.orderBy(F.col('date')) .rangeBetween(-8, Window.currentRow) )
For this, your date col should be numeric, so you can cast the date to a numeric type (number of months, seconds, ...) and in rangeBetween specify the numer of  months/seconds/... But you won't be able to use this with the ntile function. It does work with for example calculating the f.mean("score").over(w)

Comment: Well, that window with -8 on date is not what I’m looking for, it will only look eight observations back. Not take into account the values of date.

Comment: The data is not grouped on date. And should not be.

Comment: rowsBetween look at the number of rows, rangeBetween looks at the values.

Comment: okey, but what sense would -8 make? Could you provide code in the example?

Comment: -8 would be 8 less than the value in the current row. If your numeric date is in months, you'd look eight months back. If it is in days, you'd look 8 days back compared to the current row.